# How to convert linq expression to dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

can you help me, how to convert linq expression to dictionary? The following code is throwing me ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

```
        IDictionary<string, string> listAllCoursesWithAreaAsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var dictionary =
            (from b in bookListRecord
             select new { b.CourseCode, b.Area }).Distinct();

        listAllCoursesWithAreaAsDictionary = dictionary.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(x => x.CourseCode, x => x.Area); 

        return listAllCoursesWithAreaAsDictionary;
```

When I try this:

```
        listAllCoursesWithAreaAsDictionary = dictionary.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(x => x.CourseCode);
```

I get error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You might be getting "An item with the same key has already been added." because your list has a course that is available in more than one area. Are you sure a `Dictionary<string, string>` is what you need?

Comment: No, each course must always be available only in one area. It's homework to school and I must observe the interface, so I can't change Dictionary <string,string>

Comment: Well in that case I'd look at your data. If each course code existed in only one area then your first attempt would have worked, and you should not have needed the `Distinct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed with Aharon, you're looking for grouping operator:

```
  var dictionary = bookListRecord
    .GroupBy(g => g.CourseCode)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, 
      AreaList = g.Select(c => c.Area).ToList(), 
      Area = g.Select(c => c.Area).FirstOrDefault() })
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the

```
dictionary.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(x => x.CourseCode);
```

line executes your query.

In your database, where you retrieve your data from, you are receiving the same `CourseCode` twice, hence you get the error message:

```
"An item with the same key has already been added."
```

Your `Distinct()` doesn't behave as might you expect, you will have to check that. You wanted distinct by key, but you are calling distinct on an anonymous Key/Value.

Comment: thank you, guy I didn't know, the problem could be with distinct() in linq expression.